# How would this non-linear second order simultaneous differential be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

How would this non-linear second order simultaneous differential be solved? Everything other than $r(t)$ and $s(t)$ are constants and independent of time $t$. Can the runge-kutta method be applied here? If yes how and if not, are there any other numeric or analytic methods of solving this?  Also initial values are, $r(0)=0.05$ and $s(0)=0$. And, for some context, this models the decrease in hail radius due to melting as hail descents.

$$ {s}''(t)=g- \frac{3}{4} \frac{K_{1}}{\rho _{hail}} \frac{ [s^{2} (t)]'}{{}  r(t)}\\ r'(t)=-\frac{\tilde{b}\varepsilon DM_{0}}{r_{0}\rho_{i}\tilde{R} }(\frac{{e_{s}}'}{T_{s}}-\frac{e_{a}}{-40+0,0065\cdot s(t)})
$$

Comment: The standard trick is to convert a second order equation to a system of two first order equations. In you case you have one second order and one first order, so the result will be three first order equations.

Answer (score 1):

As it was pointed out in comments, if you write the problem as a system of first order differential equations, you can use any standard solver, for instance Runge-Kutta. Denoting $v = s'$, the system reads
$$
\begin{cases}
s'(t) = v(t)\\
v'(t) = c_1+c_2 \dfrac{v(t) s(t)}{r(t)}\\
r'(t) = c_3 + \dfrac{c_4}{c_5 + c_6 s(t)}
\end{cases}
$$

Apart from the initial conditions you mentioned, you also need $s'(0)$.